# Books/Resources for studying Number Theory as a First Order Theory and Model Theory

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic, model-theory

I just finished reading the completeness and compactness proofs of FOL and was wondering if there were any resources/books to study Number Theory as a First Order Theory. Can anyone provide me some useful information on this topic? Furthermore, I would like to ask if this is a suitable point for me to dive into a little bit of Model Theory, can anyone tell me? If yes, then what would be a good starting point?

Thanking You in Advance!

Comment: Maybe [**A Formal Background to Mathematics: Logic, Sets and Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038790431X) by Robert E. Edwards (1979; [review in Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1981-05-03/S0273-0979-1981-14956-9/S0273-0979-1981-14956-9.pdf)).

Comment: hi Arunavo; it might help you get more relevant answer if you clarify what you mean by "number theory as a first-order theory" here; there are a number of things that would fit the bill. for instance, do you mean first-order [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)? PA is an attempt to give a "nice" collection of axioms capturing the properties one expects to hold of structures similar to the natural numbers; by Gödel's theorem, PA is famously incomplete.

Comment: alternatively, maybe you mean "true arithmetic", ie the complete first-order theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N},\cdot,+)$? this theory is complete, and it contains all the first-order information you might want about the natural numbers, but it's much less tractable to think about than PA.

Comment: there are other relevant first-order theories and structures of interest too; some people use "number theory" to refer to the study of any [number field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field), and there is a great deal of very interesting and deep model theory around these fields. anyway, my point is that there are a number of things that could qualify as a first-order theory of number theory! if you could narrow the question down a bit you would probably be more likely to get a satisfactory answer :)

Comment: (I will make one point, which is that all of the theories listed above are quite "poorly-behaved", in a number of precise ways. so, to address your second question, there's perhaps an argument to be made that these would not be a great starting point for learning about model theory; you might be best served by learning about more "tame" theories instead. David Marker's [book](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Model_Theory_An_Introduction.html?id=QieAHk--GCcC&redir_esc=y) is a great introduction to the subject that discusses a large number of examples of first-order theories in detail!)

Comment: Thank You for the information! My aim was to study $(\mathbb{N},\cdot,+)$ first, then move on to PA once I was accustomed enough with Second Order formulation. Lastly, after gathering enough maturity I wanted to move on to Model Theory, so any books or resources that helps me develop this maturity will be much appreciated. And the last point got my attention, would you be so kind to elaborate or give examples of these "tame" theories?

Comment: Petr Hajek & Pavel Pudlak, Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic (Springer, 1993)